# PHP: Printing two files as a table

Tags: php

Keep learning PHP. Now I got a data from site out as a formatted text using regex.
Every string is in a new line in both files.
Content of the first file:

```
John
Egor
Tim
Laura
```

Content of the second file:

```
18
23
48
33
```

Need to print it out like this:

```
John  18
Egor  23
Tim   48
Laura 33
```

Code of the first file:

```
//..some regex action here ..
 foreach ($names as $name) {
        echo "$name"; 
    }
```

Where I should include this file? :

```
//..some regex action here ..
foreach ($numbers as $nr) {
    echo "$nr"; //printing
}
```

Comment: If `//..some regex action here ..` is for getting the file into an array, just use: `$array = file("yourFile.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);`